# Emit every Item od Flawable and append to List

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, android-room, reactive-programming

Can we set `Flowable` to emit every item when is ready, but append it to list (something like `buffer(int size)`  but without clear function)
I make a search query on a database that returns a `Flowable <List <ItemEntity>>` , then I map each `ItemEntity` to an `ItemDomain`, and it returns a `Flowable <List <ItemDomain>>`.
Is it possible for a `Flowable <List <ItemDomain>>` to return values sequentially, without waiting for the whole result(i.e. a one-item list first, then a two-item list, then a three-item list, etc.).
When I change my search query, I want to receive the new list again.

```
override fun observeGroupsBySearchQuery(query: String): Flowable<List<Group>> {
        return groupsDao.observeGroupsBySearchQuery(query)
            .switchMap {
                Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                    .map { group ->
                        Group(group.symbol, group.number, group.name)
                    }
                    .toList() // I dont want to wait until finish, but I dont want to loose earlier emitted items
                    .toFlowable()
            }
    }

 @Query(
            value = """
        SELECT * 
        FROM Groups 
        WHERE symbol || number || name LIKE '%' || :query || '%' AND number != -1 AND active IS 1
        """)
    abstract fun observeGroupsBySearchQuery(query: String): Flowable<List<GroupsEntity>>
```

And other interesting question is whether the database (room) can return the results one by one (do we have to use `pagination` for this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need `scan` to receive intermediate aggregates:

```java
groupsDao.observeGroupsBySearchQuery(query)
.switchMap(it ->
    Flowable.fromIterable(it)
            .map(group -> Group(group.symbol, group.number, group.name))
            .scan(new ArrayList<>(), (state, t) -> { state.add(t); return state; })
            .skip(1)
)
```

If you plan to consume the intermediate list on a different thread, you'll have to make a copy every time:

```java
            .skip(1)
            .map(list -> new ArrayList<>(list))
```